# Date Formatter string "H" is returning things with AM/PM on my phone, but not in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios11, swift4

I have the following code in my program:

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
 displayTime = formatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
 formatter.dateFormat = "H"
 let hour = formatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
 print(hour)
```

When I run this in the simulator, hour comes out to what you'd expect (e.g., 1:30PM in the timePicker --> hour = 13). However, when I run this with my actual phone, the print(hour) in the above case comes out to (1 PM). Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It's the 12/24 hours time setting in the Settings app.

Comment: It's more reliable to get the hour with `Calendar` and `DateComponents`

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think so, it's the exact same on my phone and in the simulator

Comment: You just need to set your date formatter locale to ''en_US_POSIX"